# JS, converting Array with similar values to dict

Tags: javascript

I have a list which looks like this,

```
0: (3) ["United States and Canada", "2018", 8281532000]
1: (3) ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2018", 3963707000]
2: (3) ["Latin America", "2018", 2237697000]
3: (3) ["Asia-Pacific", "2018", 945816000]
4: (3) ["United States and Canada", "2019", 10051208000]
5: (3) ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2019", 5543067000]
6: (3) ["Latin America", "2019", 2795434000]
7: (3) ["Asia-Pacific", "2019", 1469521000]
8: (3) ["United States and Canada", "2020", 5542446000]
9: (3) ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2020", 3616011000]
10: (3) ["Latin America", "2020", 1578821000]
11: (3) ["Asia-Pacific", "2020", 1052800000]
```

I want to convert it into a dict having the similar region names as key and second key being "years" and value a list with 2 more keys "year" : 2018 and "value" : 000000000.
something like,

```
[
{
    "area": "United States and Canada", 
    "years": [
        {
            "year": 2018, 
            "revenue": 11111
        }, 
        {
            "year": 2019, 
            "revenue": 22222
        }, 
        {
            "year": 2020, 
            "revenue": 333333
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Map` object to filter them out by region, then store each regions metadata into a list.

```js
const arr = [
  ["United States and Canada", "2018", 8281532000],
  ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2018", 3963707000],
  ["Latin America", "2018", 2237697000],
  ["Asia-Pacific", "2018", 945816000],
  ["United States and Canada", "2019", 10051208000],
  ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2019", 5543067000],
  ["Latin America", "2019", 2795434000],
  ["Asia-Pacific", "2019", 1469521000],
  ["United States and Canada", "2020", 5542446000],
  ["Europe,  Middle East and Africa", "2020", 3616011000],
  ["Latin America", "2020", 1578821000],
  ["Asia-Pacific", "2020", 1052800000]
];

const convert = (list) => {
  const regionMap = new Map();
  const result = [];

  for (let item of list) {
    // If that region hasn't been defined yet, create a new. list for it
    if (!regionMap.has(item[0])) regionMap.set(item[0], []);
    // Add a new { year, revenue } entry for the current region
    regionMap.get(item[0]).push({
      year: item[1],
      revenue: item[2]
    });
  }

  for (let entry of [...regionMap.entries()]) {
    result.push({
      area: entry[0],
      years: entry[1]
    });
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(convert(arr));
```